# Map an XML list into a Word repeating component (Word 2013)

Tags: xml, excel, ms-word, schema, repeat

I have an xml file that I have generated from an excel spreadsheet.
This xml represents the rows and columns of the spreadsheet.

For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns="dummy.xsd">
    <record>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <Sales>16753</Sales>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Quarter>Qtr 3</Quarter>
    </record>
    <record>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
        <Sales>14808</Sales>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Quarter>Qtr 4</Quarter>
    </record>
    <record>
        <LastName>Williams</LastName>
        <Sales>10644</Sales>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Quarter>Qtr 2</Quarter>
    </record>
<data-set>
```

I would like to be able to go through each row and display each part of it into a word component, so that I can format it with word formats.

So I would have something like (With [[..]]  Symbolizing the components and repeat-structure)

```
[[
    [[
        [[Lastname]]   -    [[Sales]] - [[Contry]] - [[Repeat]]
    ]]
    [[
        [[Lastname]]   -    [[Sales]] - [[Contry]] - [[Repeat]]
    ]]
]]
```

I have already opened the **Developer Pane**, and load my xml with the *(Add new part...)* function of the *XML Mapping* Pane.

When I right-click on a tag of the XML hierarchy, and do *Insert Content Control > Repeating", this creates a word component with the following text:

> "Enter any content that you want to repeat, including other content controls. You can also insert this control around table rows in order to repeat parts of a table."

If I put some of the *record* field in it, it (*Insert Content Control > PlainText*), it tells be:

> "Plain text controls cannot be inserted aroud the current selection"

I also tried to put a schema in *Developer > Add-Ins > XML Schema > Add Schema"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My blog post [word-2013-repeatingsection-content-controls-ready-for-prime-time](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2015/01/word-2013-repeatingsection-content-controls-ready-for-prime-time/)
may be of interest (including the [linked docx](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docs/developer/w15RepeatingSection_cf_OpenDoPE.docx?raw=true), which contains some hints/learnings re the Mapping Pane)

The later post [i-have-my-xml-now-what](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2015/01/i-have-my-xml-now-what/) points to a service which will generate repeating structures from your sample XML.

Answer (score 2):

I finally achieve it doing so:

1. Activate the "Developer Pane" in the "Ribbon"
2. Open "XML Mapping Pane"
3. Choose "Developer > XML Mapping > Custom XML Part > Add new part (...)" and select the  XML
4. Then select the XML file in the list "Custom XML Part"  and on an item of the list right click and select "Insert Content Control > Repeating"
   This should create a kind of "double tags" in the document
5. Then, DON'T activate the "Design Mode" ("Developer > Design Mode")   (Or else it will complain)

   - Position the mouse cursor inside the "double tags" that have been created in the page   (In the place of "Enter any content that you want to repeat, including other content controls. You can also insert this control around table rows in order to repeat parts of a table.")
   - And right click on a field of an item in the "XML Mapping Pane" and choose "Insert content control > Plain text"
     This shall create a new "single tag" which represent the field in the word page (nested in a "double tag" that represent the "foreach")
   - Switch OFF the Design Mode (and ON and OFF again if needed). The items shall be displayed and contain the field that was inserted

The only problem is that it is veeeeeery slow. I tried to map a 100 rows XML (with 2 columns only) and in took almost 5 minutes.